# how to add map image in amcharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

function mapChart(){

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("mapChart", {
"type": "map",
```

"dataProvider": {
    "map": "worldLow",
    "images": getData(),
     "areas": [
                { "id": "PK", "color": "#CC0000" },

```
        ],
},

"areasSettings": {
"autoZoom": true,
"selectedColor": "#CC0000"
```

},

"smallMap": {}
} );

function getData(){

```
    var final = [];
    $.get('map_chart_fetch.php',function(data){
        var mapData = JSON.parse(data);
        for(var i=0; i< mapData.length; i++){
            final.push({
                "latitude":mapData[i].latitude,
                "longitude":mapData[i].longitude,
                "color": "#eea638",
                "type": "circle"
            });
        }




    });
    return final;

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Probably your chart gets initialized before the ajax request completes. There are many ways to fix this, like raising events once the ajax request completes and then listening to those events and initializing the chart.

A simpler approach could be to initialize the chart in the success callback of your ajax request, right after you populate the 'final' object.